# Can't start or list docker Machines created on another partition

Tags: docker, docker-machine

On two separate PC`s, one with Windows using Hyper-V and another one with Windows using virtual-box,  I created a new docker machine with the following command:

`docker-machine -s D:\Projects create --driver virtualbox myenv1
docker-machine -s D:\Projects create --driver hyperv myenv2`

As one may notice, i intend to do not use the main C: partition, because i cannot afford space. 
Althoug the machines are created, I cant start them or list them with **docker-machine start myenv1**, not even docker-machine ls shows me anything.

Any ideias?

Comment: Are there any errors when running the commands? Please add the `--debug` option to the command and post the debug output as it can be helpful for solving.

Comment: No there is not! It goes without errors but the machine does not appear on docker-machine ls...
Above the debug output

Comment: ```
Docker is up and running!
(myenv1) Calling .GetConfigRaw
To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this virtual machine, run: D:\Programas\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe env myenv1
Successfully made call to close driver server
Making call to close connection to plugin binary
(myenv1) DBG | Closing plugin on server side
Making call to close driver server
Successfully made call to close driver server
Making call to close connection to plugin binary
(flag-lookup) DBG | Closing plugin on server side
```